# K-fold cross validation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

How do i perform k-fold cross validation on a data set, say X.

I have gone through the matlab site and have tried this for a data set X.
Following is the code for 10 fold cross validation on set X.

```
c= cvcrossvalidate(X,'kFold',10);
```

This creates an object `c`, but how do i access the different parts and use them to test my classifier? I am not able to comprehend even after going through various texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this:

```
C = crossvalind('Kfold', X_label, 10);
for i = 1:10                             
    Test = (C == i); 
    Train = ~Test;                  
    SVMStruct = svmtrain ( X (Train,:), X_label (Train,:));
    Result = svmclassify(SVMStruct, X (Test,:));
end
```

`X_label` = your data labelling.

`X` = your data set.

Comment: Why apply crossvalind only to the labels..what about X? and what does Test=(C==i); mean.. and the next line as well..would you be kind enough to explain the code?

Comment: `K-fold` is the best way to test your data in addition to get very high performance. It works like this: 
(1)- `C` will carried a data labels and 10 random samples (for testing). 
(2)- inside loop, let variable `Test` take one sample from random 10 samples that already in `C`. (3)- `Train = ~Test` means use all other data (except the sample in `Test`) as a training data. So you have only one sample in `Test` and all other samples in `Train`.
next loop will choose new sample as a `Test` and other samples as a `Train` >> and go like this. Good luck